# Photo Uploading not working for the last two days

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just saw it is working for others. I dont know whether it is working to everyone, or just working to few people.

My coding is not suddenly working for the last two days.
It is PHP graph api

```
$facebook->api('/me/photos?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $arguments);
```

This is how it is uploaded.
Nothing was changed. It was working fine. It is all not working for the last two days.

Error is

```
OAuthException: (#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag
```

$arguments is an array which contains the image, tags (which is also an array) and message

Comment: Please show what you're passing in the `$arguments` data. I guess you're trying to tag people in the image, but you're not specifying the x,y coordinates for the tags (within the picture)

Comment: @scibuff array('tag_uid'=>$tag_id, 'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y); I am passing x and y coordinate. I promise it was working and i saw the tags. last two days it is not working

Comment: :) Is facebook api working differently on different region? I mean could it be a problem in api or my side?

Comment: Any help? Any clue? I am trying it for last two days, i didnt get any idea to fix it. Even i dont know whether it is script problem or api problem

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the changes (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/) Facebook just introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem! The same code, but don't work for the past 24 hours.

I use graph api via Action Script. I HTTP POST a request with a parameter Object, which contains tag_uid, x, and y. Bad request just as following:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

The API didn't recognize the x parameter and y parameters.  So, I tried to use the api method `/photoID/tags`. This way works without specifying the x and y parameters, if you do specify them, it won't work.

Comment: I haven't used photoid/tag method. How will it tag user in the exact position if we didn't send the x and y? Can you share any example for this method?

Comment: After wasting two, three days, you save the rest of the day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

> **tags**
>
> Comma-separated list of Facebook IDs of people tagged in this Post. For example: 1207059,701732. This field is returned as the
> with_tags field when the Post is read.
> **NOTE:** *You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.*

So I think you should also specify the place (page Id of the location associated with the post) in order to put tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add ***place*** value to the params. ***place*** value is page_id in facebook.

sample actionscript code is as following

```
tagArr = '[{"tag_uid":"' + String(userVO.uid) + '", "x":"1", "y":"1"}]';
var params:Object = {access_token:userVO.accessToken, place:"123456789", tags:tagArr, image:bitmap, message:msg, fileName:'FILE_NAME'};
Facebook.api('/'+userVO.uid+'/photos', onCompleteHandler, params);
```