# Facebook application photo tag

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

While uploading a photo from my application I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag thrown in

By this I am getting the photo tag id array

```php
$friends = $this->facebook->api('/me/friends');
shuffle($friends['data']);
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    $arr[''.$i.'']['tag_uid'] = $friend['id'];
    $arr[''.$i.'']['x'] = '11';
    $arr[''.$i.'']['y'] = '12';
    $i++;
    if ($i == 25) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And this is for uploading the photo

```php
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> '' . $image_name['image_caption'] . ' for more LoL Images check out - http://lolsharing.com/',
    'tags'=> $arr
);

$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('' . FCPATH . 'assets/joke_images/' . $image_name['image_name'] . '');

$upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/' . $create_album['id'] . '/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

It was working properly before but i don't know why it is not working now.
Please help me with this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As explained here:

[Photo Uploading not working for the last two days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618613/photo-uploading-not-working-for-the-last-two-days)

apparently now the Graph API requires a place value to be specified whenever you tag someone: incredibly stupid, IMHO, since the website doesn't have the same restrictions.

Comment: I think I found a workaround, though: if you add tags after you upload the picture, the place is not required